# P: Archivos | Struct

Tags: c

Buenas Tengo un error la linea que sería la 7, ( la linea que se encuentra arriba de la struct )
Alguien sabe porque me tira error? el error es el siguiente

"**error: array type has incomplete element type 'struct VehiculoE'**"

el error me lo tira en lo siguiente:

```
int buscarVehiculoNombre(struct VehiculoE e[],int t,char Buscado[50]); // acá es la liena 7
```

---

pd: en los archivos se encuentran vehiculos en este formato: Vehiculo#Patente

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CANTIDAD 100

struct VehiculoE pasarCharAstruct(char aux[],int t);
int buscarVehiculoNombre(struct VehiculoE e[],int t,char Buscado[50]); // acá es la liena 7


struct VehiculoE{

  char modelo[50];
  char patente[50];

};


int main(void)
{
char aux[50];

struct VehiculoE a[100];

int i=0;

    FILE * vehiculos = fopen("Vehiculos.txt","r");
while(!feof(vehiculos)){
    fgets(aux,50,vehiculos);
    a[i] = pasarCharAstruct(aux,50);
    i++;

}
    fclose(vehiculos);

    char auxN[50];
    printf("\nIngrese el nombre del vehiculo a buscar: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(auxN);

    if(buscarVehiculoNombre(a,CANTIDAD,auxN) != -1){
        printf("ENCONTRADO");
    }else{
        printf("NO ENCONTRADO");
    }


    return 0;
}
struct VehiculoE pasarCharAstruct(char aux[],int t){

char auxVehiculo[50] = " ";
char auxPatente[50] = " ";
int flag = -1;

for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    if(aux[i] == '#'){
        flag = i;
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<flag;i++){

    auxVehiculo[i] = aux[i];
}
for(int i=flag+1;i<t;i++){
    auxPatente[i-flag-1] = aux[i];
}

struct VehiculoE a1;

strcpy(a1.modelo,auxVehiculo);
strcpy(a1.patente,auxPatente);

return a1;

}
int buscarVehiculoNombre(struct VehiculoE e[],int t,char Buscado[50]){

int flag = -1;

for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
    if(strcmp(e[i].modelo,Buscado) == 0){

        flag = i;
    }

}
printf("\nFLAG ----> %d",flag);
return flag;

}
```

Lo que no entiendo es porque cuando elimino la linea 7 el programa funciona bien

Comment: Tienes que definir la estructura antes de ocuparla. Mueve la declaración antes de la línea 7, inmediatamente después del último #define.

Comment: Que boludo que soy jajajaj, gracias!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El orden importa en C. Primero declara la `struct`, luego ocupa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define CANTIDAD 100

struct VehiculoE{

  char modelo[50];
  char patente[50];

};

struct VehiculoE pasarCharAstruct(char aux[],int t);
int buscarVehiculoNombre(struct VehiculoE e[],int t,char Buscado[50]);
```

Adicionalmente, estás usando `gets`, lo que no es aconsejable. Usa `fgets`, con lo que evitares posibles `buffer overflow`.

```
char auxN[50];
printf("\nIngrese el nombre del vehiculo a buscar: ");
fflush(stdin);
fgets(auxN, sizeof(auxN), stdin);
```

`fgets` se asegura de que no ingresen más caracteres que los soportados por el buffer.

Debes indicarle:

- El buffer donde recibiras los caracteres (`auxN`).
- El espacio disponible, `sizeof(auxN)`. `fgets` leera hasta N-1 caracteres y luego agregara un 0 para marcar el final de la cadena.
- De donde lo estás leyendo. En este caso, `stdin`